# Populate Repeater after TextBox is cleared

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a standard repeater, which is populated with a default list of images in code-behind:

```
Repeater.DataSource = ImageList;
Repeater.DataBind();
```

I have a TextBox, for which I use this script to clear it, whenever you click on it:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type=text]').focus(function () {
        $(this).val('');
    });
});
```

The DataSource for my Repeater might change from time to time and I want to bind the above default ImageList to it whenever the TextBox is cleared. I couldn't think of any solution, so I'm grateful for any advice.

Comment: Build repeater on client side and use ajax

Comment: @Santosh Sadly, I cannot do that. The repeater has to be on Server side..

Answer (score 0):

Add next method to your code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static int BindRepeater(int justparam)
{
    int result = 0;
    Repeater.DataSource = ImageList;
    Repeater.DataBind();
    return result;
}
```

And jquery to your design page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#textboxid').change(function(){
        if ($('#textboxid').value == '')
            BindRepeat();
    }

    function BindRepeat(){
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "YourPagesName.aspx/BindRepeater",
                data: "{justparam: '2'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('Works');
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: That looks like it could work! I'll test it as soon as I get home. Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry for my lack of Knowledge, but how exactly do I include the jquery in my design page? I've added a line: <script src="Scripts/jquery-defaultPopulate.js" type="text/javascript"></script> but this does not seem to work (the jquery is called jquery-defaultPopulate.js)

Comment: add *<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" >< / script >* between your *head* tags, then do: *<script type="text/javascript">that code </script>*

Comment: I've done that, but it still does not work. While Debugging, the application does not even enter the code-behind function BindRepeater.

Comment: did you add following namespaces? 
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

Comment: Yes, I made sure my Visual Studio can recognize the WebMethod and ScriptMethod classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100983/discussion-between-khazratbek-and-kohnarik).